# Openpyxl returns values as number instead of text

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to load a excel file to get values to be used for displaying purposes.

```
wb = load_workbook(xlsx_file, data_only=True)
first_sheet = wb.get_sheet_names()[0]
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(first_sheet)

for row in ws.rows[1:]:
    serial_no = row[0].value
```

Some of the values in my excel file contains pure numbers (e.g. 91234567 which returns me 91234567.0) and there are times where the values contains a mix of strings and numbers (e.g. 1234abc567). Is there a way for me to get my values as strings instead of floats?

For more information, I am using openpyxl 2.3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for row in ws.rows[1:]:
    try:
        serial_no = str(int(row[0].value))
    except ValueError:
        serial_no = str(row[0].value)
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I am looking for